# jQuery validation message issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three input radio buttons like

```
<input type="radio" name="specific_parent" id="parent_one" class="radio" value="existing_parent"><label class="redio_label" for="existing_parent">Existing Parent</label>
<input type="radio" name="specific_parent" id="parent_two" class="radio" value="prospective_parent"><label class="redio_label" for="prospective_parent">Prospective Parent</label>
<input type="radio" name="specific_parent" id="parent_third" class="radio" value="other"><label class="redio_label" for="other">Other</label>
```

I have applied jQuery validation like this:

```
rules: {
   specific_parent: {
      required: true
   }
},
messages: {
  specific_parent: {
      required: 'Please select radio button'
  }
}
```

problem is that it display the error message after first input radio button and my layout is break.

[image]

Comment: where do you want to display it?

Comment: And exactly what validation plugin are you using?

Comment: under all three radio buttons!!

Comment: Where is the code that displays the message?

Comment: jQuery Validation Plugin v1.13.1
 * http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @HamzaKubba I have already added the jQuery code at above that display the message.

Comment: Any css or jquery approach for me??

Comment: @ Iffi share some `fiddle` link

Comment: That's not jQuery code, those are the settings for the plugin you're using (in JSON, not Javascript)... anyway, the website you linked to seems to be down right now, so I can't see how it works, so I can't suggest a solution. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use errorPlacement

```
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      error.insertBefore(element);
}
```

Comment: Is there any function like insertBefore() to put the errors after element??

Comment: Yes there are functions error.insertBefore(element) and       error.insertAfter(element);

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-container">
<input type="radio" name="specific_parent" id="parent_one" class="radio" value="existing_parent"><label class="redio_label" for="existing_parent">Existing Parent</label>
<input type="radio" name="specific_parent" id="parent_two" class="radio" value="prospective_parent"><label class="redio_label" for="prospective_parent">Prospective Parent</label>
<input type="radio" name="specific_parent" id="parent_third" class="radio" value="other"><label class="redio_label" for="other">Other</label>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
 .input-container{position:relative;} 
</style>
```

you have to add css of your parent div of inputs then change the position of error message using positon absolute in css and using top,left or bottom properties you can adjust where you want to display.